# Grouping samples for snakemake workflow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, snakemake

I have a data table which is formatted as following:

```
| Read1      | Read2      | Group | SampleID |
| ---------- | ---------- | ----- | -------- |
| file.fq.gz | file.fq.gz | 1     | 1.1      |
| file.fq.gz | file.fq.gz | 2     | 2.1      |
| file.fq.gz | file.fq.gz | 3     | 3.1      |
| file.fq.gz | file.fq.gz | 2     | 2.2      |
| file.fq.gz | file.fq.gz | 1     | 1.2      |
| file.fq.gz | file.fq.gz | 2     | 2.3      |
```

Where the Read columns contain directory information for these files, and the group number is the only relevant feature. I am looking for a way to pass the reads belonging to rows of a specific group 1,2,and 3 respectively to snakemake, in order to perform a process involving all of these files. I know a for loop could work, such as:

```
for x in [1,2,3]: 
  subset = df[df['Group'] == x] 
  analyze_subset_etc
```

However is there a more efficient way to do this which would better utilize the resources
and computational efficiency of snakemake?

**Further clarification:**

The main steps of the workflow are needing to be performed for each row of the dataframe, so those steps would be like:

```py
def r1(sample):
    return df.loc[sample, 'Read1']
def r2(sample):
    return df.loc[sample, 'Read2']

rule trim_reads:
   input:
      read1 = r1
      read2 = r2
   etc
```

Based on this framework it is difficult to pass all the samples by group, as they are not unique. Thus, I'm looking for a different way to couple these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without more detail about what you need to do. Maybe something along these lines?

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand('{group}.txt', group=[1, 2, 3]),

rule one:
    output:
        '{group}.txt',
    run:
        subset = df[df['Group'] == wildcards.group]
        analyze_subset_etc(subset)
```

Comment: Sure, I could give some more details, thanks for your response! Updating the main question